# WPF Treeview Using Catel 4

Tags: catel

Can anyone guide me in using Catel 4 and a WPF TreeView control? I'm trying to create something like the VS solution explorer. I have created models and VMs for each level of the tree.

When I add a hierarchical data template (HDT) and use the VM types for the DataType parameters, I get a tree showing the top-level collection member types. That is, WPF couldn't match the ItemsSource collection types to my HDT. If I change the HDT to use the model types, the TreeView behaves properly, but now my VMs aren't being used.

Thanks.

-reilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to make every element inside the tree a view model (performance wise). A treeview (like the solution explorer) should be a single view model with models that contain nested models. So your model will be a complete object graph representing the items in the tree.

Comment: But how to cleanly manage some attributes like collapsed or expanded state which is more belonging to the view than to the model? I used a lean viewmodel in such a case but performance wise this is not really optimal like you noticed.

Comment: I would make specific models (wrappers) for the treelist items that contains the state / children shown in the view. It's the best thing you can do without having a performance impact.