# Catel: Treeview HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, catel

I have started create a small test application for MVVM with Catel. I tryed to show a TreeView and create one ViewModel to display all the Items. But I get an Error.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ChildCollection}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildCollection}">
            <local:TreeViewItem DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>nter code here
```

The `TreeViewItem` is only an `TextBlock`. But because it's an userControl, Catel should create the ViewModel for it. The following code of the ViewModel is simplified.

```
public class TreeViewItemVm : ViewModelBase
{
    public TreeViewItemVm(ModelBase model)
    {
        Model = model;

        if(model is Group)
            // Set Properties
        else if(model is Customer)
            // Set Properties
        else if(model is Product)
            // Set Properties
    }

    [Model]
    public ModelBase Model {get; set; }
    public string DisplayText {get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> ChildCollection {get; set; }
    public Command OpenItemCommand { get; private set; }
```

On running this, I get the error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ChildCollection' property not found on 'object' ''Customer' ...

So `HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildCollection}"` is looking on the Model instead of the ViewModel.

The Model should not implement the Command. So the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612502/7790628) here isn't specific enought. Is there a way to achive this? Or do I have to define it explicit for echt type with its own CustomControl, like it's done in this basic [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step/). Or does anyone knows an Catel specific example?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootTreeViewItemVms}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType={x:Type TreeViewItemVm} 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ChildCollection}">
                <TextBlock Text={Binding DisplayText} />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You should also have specific ViewModel types that inherit from a base TreeViewItemVm.

```
public abstract class TreeViewItemVm: ViewModelBase
{
    public TreeViewItemVm()
    {
        ChildCollection = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemVm>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemVm> ChildCollection {get; }
    public Command OpenItemCommand { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayText {get; set; }
}

public abstract class TreeViewItemVm<T> where T: ModelBase
{
    public TreeViewItemVm(T model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public T Model {get;}
}

public class GroupTreeViewItemVm: TreeViewItem<Group>
{
    public GroupTreeViewItemVm(Group group): base(group)
    {
        // group specific stuff here
    }
}

etc....
```

If required you can make different HierarchicalDataTemplates for each specific ViewModel type.

**edit**

There is also a flaw in your TreeViewItemVm class.

```
public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> ChildCollection {get; set; }
```

should be

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemVm> ChildCollection {get; set; }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but this doesn't work. I get the same error message. The constructors will not be called. This doesn’t solve the problem, that it looks on the model for the `ChildCollection`, instead to create the ViewModel for it. Is this answer really Catel specific?

PS: I changed your code, so that the BaseClass and the generic one has different names and that the generic one inherits from the BaseClass. Also, I changed `ItemType` to `DataType`.

Comment: @RCP161 This is why I never use one of the MVVM frameworks that does "magic" behind the scenes - relying on classes being named in a certain manner, rather than explicitly manually declaring the classes and bindings.